# Can the Caches directory be emptied during app runtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

We're saving our Core Data and other objects in the Caches directory. It's OK if they're deleted, but it becomes messy if they disappear during the app runtime. Can this actually happen, or can we assume that once a file has been created it'll be there for the rest of app's runtime?

Comment: accordingly to the documentation the information in this directory can be deleted at any time if the system get out of space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table 1-3](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) says:

> ...the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the
>   system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app
>   is running.

That's good, then :-)

Answer (score -1):

> The NSCache class incorporates various auto-removal policies, which
>   ensure that it does not use too much of the system’s memory. The
>   system automatically carries out these policies if memory is needed by
>   other applications. When invoked, these policies remove some items
>   from the cache, minimizing its memory footprint

you can see the doc : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/CachingPurgeableMemory/Introduction/Introduction.html

the cache has a cost limits , if your file is larger than the threshold it will auto-removal.
but you can control them with `countLimit` , `totalCostLimit` properties and you can add object with cost, look at `setObject:forKey:cost:`.

Also you can evict objects by yourself. Add NSDiscardableContent protocol implementation to your objects and `setEvictsObjectsWithDiscardedContent:` to `YES`.

but when your cache is larger , when your app runs in background , the cache will evict some of objects (maybe all)

Comment: While NSCache is awesome, I was asking about the Caches *directory* (as received through the NSCachesDirectory flag) :-)